# Is it possible to install the Ubuntu SDK in Gentoo?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sdk

Is it possible to install the Ubuntu SDK and all the tools needed to develop apps for Ubuntu in another Linux distribution, lets say: Sabayon (a Gentoo derivative), or any other Linux distro that is not Ubuntu?

Comment: You'll have to install all the dependencies manually, but you should be able to do that. It's GNU/Linux after all. Have you actually tried?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question, though I'm using a different GNU/Linux distribution. Why is this off-topic? Doesn't if fall into the "Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical." category?
I haven't tried to build it yet because launchpad is extremely confusing to me. Which all [all these repositories](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team) am I meant to clone and build??