# How to install the Ubuntu SDK on Debian?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, debian, ubuntu-sdk

Is it possible to get the Ubuntu SDK on Debian?
These PPA things look like links.. and definitely don't work on a Debian system.
Any thoughts on that? Or is this a crappy idea?

I just want to play around a little with ub.touch and maybe program some small apps for desktop or touch. (Probably just touch, so I won't have to remove Debian and install Ubuntu - seems like a waste of time)

Somehow its related to:
[Is it possible to install the Ubuntu SDK in Gentoo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339416/is-it-possible-to-install-the-ubuntu-sdk-in-gentoo)
but specific for Debian, which shouldn't be too different to Ubuntu.

Comment: Close voters, Debian/Ubuntu crosswork is on topic: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/745/when-are-debian-questions-offtopic

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping it from working on Debian except somebody doing the packaging work.  You will need the SDK components and all their dependencies (upstream qt5, for example).  You also won't be able to use things like the Ubuntu Online Accounts and Ubuntu One APIs unless the desktop services backing them are also ported.

Comment: I've been thinking about packaging at least the ui-toolkit bits for Debian. The main issue (I foresee without having done any work yet) is that sid is already on Qt 5.1).